# Having an issue with using structs in my fractions program

Tags: c++

Here is my program. It is supposed to take 2 fractions and add them together while modeling structs. I am having some trouble with it. I am getting a few error messages. Copy this code and see if you can debug it correctly for me and explain what you did. I am very stuck! Thank you very much!

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

/*
Name: Fraction
Author: Grant Birkinbine
Date: 13/10/14 17:33
Description: Takes two fractions and outputs them in different ways
*/

using namespace std;

//Struct

struct fraction{
   int numer, denom ;
};

//Function to print fractions

void displayfractionadd (fraction a) { 
 cout << "Addition: " << add.numer << "/" << add.denom << endl;

}

//Function to get fraction info

fraction newfraction() {
     fraction a1;
     cout << "Enter numerator: " ;
     cin >> a1.numer ;
     cout << "Enter denomerator: " ;
     cin >> a1.denom ;
     return a1;
}

//Function to add fractions

fraction addition(fraction a1, fraction a2) {
fraction add;
add.denom = (a1.denom * a2.denom) ;
add.numer = a1.numer * a2.denom + a1.denom * a2.numer;
return add;
}

//Main     

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

cout << "Fraction 1 = " ;
cout << endl;
fraction fraction1 = newfraction();
fraction fraction2 = newfraction();
cout << endl;
cout << "Solutions: " ;
fraction newadd = addition(fraction a1, fraction a2) ;
cout << endl;
displayfractionadd (fraction a);

system("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: If you get error messages, please post them.

Comment: `Copy this code and see if you can debug it correctly for me` How about "no"? include your error messages. At least tell us if they are runtime or compile time...

Comment: The errors that I get are compiler errors. I get an error on line 23 stating that 'add' is undeclared. Also errors on line 58 stating that 'a1' and 'a2' are undeclared. There is also an error on line 60 stating that 'a' is also undeclared.

Comment: @Alphabert Which lines are line 23, 58, and 60?

Answer (score 1):

These lines do not call functions:

```
fraction newadd = addition(fraction a1, fraction a2) ;
//...
displayfractionadd (fraction a);
```

Those lines declare functions, not call them. To call a function, just provide the parameters:

```
fraction newadd = addition(a1, a2);
//...
displayfractionadd (a);
```

Second, `a`, `a1` and `a2` are not declared anywhere.  Did you mean `fraction1` `fraction2`, and `newadd`?

```
fraction newadd = addition(fraction1, fraction2);
//...
displayfractionadd (newadd);
```

Last, unless you have a specific reason for doing so, pass `fraction` by `reference` or `const reference`, not by value.  For example:

```
fraction addition(const fraction& a1, const fraction& a2)
{
  //... body of function here
}
```

Since both a1 and a2 are not changed within the `addition` function, the parameters should be const references to indicate (and enforce) that a1 and a2 are not changed.  In addition, passing by reference does not invoke an extraneous copy.

Comment: The errors that I get are compiler errors. I get an error on line 23 stating that 'add' is undeclared. Also errors on line 58 stating that 'a1' and 'a2' are undeclared. There is also an error on line 60 stating that 'a' is also undeclared. What can I do to fix these?

Comment: @Alphabert - Where did you declare `a1` and `a2`?